# How does $wpdb->insert_id acts in a multithread / high traffic environment?

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, wordpress

I'm writing a wordpress plugin which needs to set data to the database. I've created several tables which uses `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the field `ID` (the primary key).

As far as I know you can use `$wpdb->insert_id` to get the value of the last `AUTO_INCREMENT` id (which was created usually by an insert-statement). This sound fine but I'm in doubt that it will work in an environment with high traffic where many tables with different `AUTO_INCREMENT` id are processed. I guess `insert_id` could be overwritten by a different thread in this case.

Question:
Is `$wpdb->insert_id` a solution on a high traffic site? Is there any better approach to get the last inserted object (current thread) using wpdb?

Comment: It will work. People have thought of the same problem and solved it for guys like us. You'll get the last auto_increment for THAT session (connection to mysql).

Comment: Thank you N.B. - you mean THAT thread (worker of the http Request) or THAT session which may lead into MultiThread troubles. Thank you!

Comment: You'll find more specialists at [wordpress.se], but please note that is **not ok** to [duplicate questions on the network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/185667). Also make sure to research site before posting, as the question may have been asked before. And my 2 cents, WP has many estructural problems but I doubt AUTO_INCREMENT is a issue as we can run huge sites with the engine, see: [wordpress.com](https://en.wordpress.com/stats/) and [HyperDB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/).

Comment: Thank you brasofilo for your comment. I do not duplicate questions and I choose to use stackoverflow. I've done researches before posting this topic and I found no other question like this. Second, the question was not about AUTO_INCREMENT - please read carefully before posting a reply. It's about wpdb + insert_id and how threadsafe it is implemented. Anyway thanks for your attempt to say something meaningful.

Comment: i think you are getting confused? $wpdb->insert_id will only be overwritten by the next wpdb operation in the current session, so you can use it in code following the insertion. If you need to access the id somewhere else, you need to save it somewhere. Other operations in different php sessions will not effect. Its the same as all object properties set in php.